# Conditional search with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to convert the following `MYSQL` query to `PDO` statement with prepare and execute functions but as I'm new in `PDO` I have no idea that how can I convert it to `PDO` statement! Any ideas?

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=MYDBNAME;host=MYHOST', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');

$searchName = $db->quote($_GET["searchstr"]);

$searchTerms = explode(' ', $searchName);
$searchTermBits = array();

foreach ($searchTerms as $term)
{
    $term = trim($term);
    if (!empty($term)) 
            $searchTermBits[] = "f_name LIKE '%$term%' OR l_name LIKE '%$term%'";
    else
            $searchTermBits[] = "f_name = '$term'";
}

$mysqlResult = $db->query("SELECT * FROM food_tbl WHERE (" . implode(' OR ', $searchTermBits) . ")  AND country_id = 1 ORDER BY id DESC;");
```

Comment: Look in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php

Comment: @luk2302 I know that how can I work with `PDO`, my main problem is that I can't convert the above search query to `PDO` statement query.

Comment: There is no PDO-code in your snippet, provide the PDO-code you have already so we can improve that.

Comment: @luk2302 Okay update my code with PDO-code, I wrote it with plain query function, can you improve it with prepare and execute functions?

Comment: If you were more certain with question title, making it something like "conditional search with PDO" instead of too broad "convert from mysql to PDO", you'd had you answer already, from the "Related" section. As it was obviously asked many times already

Comment: @YourCommonSense I already searched about this topic but I couldn't find any similar solution in this case!

Comment: I know, I have difficulties with search on this site myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// sanitize and build the searchTerms from the incoming `searchstr`
$searchTerms = !empty($_GET['searchstr'])
             ? explode(' ', $_GET['searchTerms'])
             : array();

// setup a dynamic list of arguments being passed in
$where = array();
$params = array();
foreach ($searchTerms as $term) {
  $term = trim($term);
  if (!empty($term){
    $where[] = 'l_name LIKE ?';
    $params[] = $term;
  }
  $where[] = 'f_name ' . (empty($term) ? '=' : 'LIKE') . ' ?';
  $params[] = $term;
}

// establish a new PDO object
$db = new PDO('...');

// prepare your query statement using the "static" query and a compiled
// query built from the above loop.
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT   * '
                    . 'FROM     food_tbl '
                    . 'WHERE    country_id = 1 '
                    . '  AND    (' . implode(' OR ', $where) . ') '
                    . 'ORDER BY id DESC');
// pass in the list of parameters from the above loop to the prepared
// statement and return the result
$result = $query->execute($params);

/* Work with $result */
```

You can dynamically populate `$where` and `$params` as a 1:1 parameter-to-value list, then build your query from the `$where` list and pass in the matching `$params` list.

I recommend saving the actual query off to a variable before passing it to `$db->prepare()` and `echo`/`var_dump` it (along with `$params`) so you can see what is being handed off to the PDO. Sometimes a picture is worth 1000 words and visualizing it makes it a little bit less like a black box and easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks but it's return nothing, here is the SQL from var_dump: `object(PDOStatement)#5 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(152) "SELECT * FROM food_tbl WHERE country_id = 1 AND (f_name LIKE ? OR l_name LIKE ?) ORDER BY id DESC;"}`

Comment: @iSun: that looks correct. what about the `$params` array?

Comment: Done, by adding % in `$params` array.

Comment: Is it safe from SQL injection?

Comment: @iSun: as long as you use `$params[] = '%' . $term . '%';` you should be good.